# Is flight training on Russian planes performed in Russian?

Tags: flight-training

When doing flight training in a Russian plane (e.g. Tupolev, Antonov, etc.), does the flight instructor speak Russian or English?

Comment: Are you talking about a pilot training for a private license (small GA), a military pilot or a commercial pilot?

Comment: And where are you talking about flying? In Russia they will speak Russian, in the USA they'll typically speak English.

Comment: @J.Hougaard I am talking about a commercial pilot. Like those flight training in Russian planes e.g. Tupolev, Anotonov, etc.

Comment: @GdD do you mean in Russia pilots speak Russian to ATC?

Comment: @LeonardTan Please clarify the question a bit more. Are you asking about a Russian commercial pilot training in Russia on a Russian aircraft or just in general any commercial pilot somewhere in the world training in a Russian aircraft?

Comment: @LeonardTan yes, generally they will. Russian is an official ICAO language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of unclear, but this would be dependent upon the country in which the flight training is taking place. If the training is taking place in Russia, most likely the instructor would speak to the student in Russian. If in the United States, the instructor would speak to the student in English.  As for ATC  transmissions, the only time the flight crew would be required to speak in English would be on an IFR flight plan. Any other time, they would speak their native language on the radio.

Comment: Pilots can speak their own native language to the ATC? I never knew this was allowed. I thought you are only allowed to speak English to ATC.

Comment: Only for IFR flights

Comment: @Leonard, Not only. Domestic flights in Russia use Russian. So I believe French in France.